# How to build object from array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 `input` div and each div has multiple inputs. I would like to build an object from an array. I looped from the input element to get each value, then I'm trying to save the index of `input` div in the object that I have built as I want to group them in an object as designed in HTML., but I'm not getting all the values saved in the `data` variable. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Here's the HTML markup and JS:-

```js
var data = [];

$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.input input').each(function(i) {
    var index = $(this).parent().parent().prevAll().length;
    var obj = {};
    
    obj.text = $(this).val();
    obj.radio = $(this).val();
    
    data.push({
      index: index,
      obj: obj
    });
    
  });
  
  var inputs = [];
  $.each(data, function() {
    inputs[this.index] = this.obj;
  });
  
  console.log(inputs);
});
```

```css
.input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="input">
    <strong>Test 1</strong>
    <div class="text">
      <input type="text" value="test" />
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-1-yes" name="input-1" value="Input 1: Yes" checked>
   <label for="input-1-yes">Input 1: Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-1-no" name="input-1" value="Input 1: No">
   <label for="input-2-no">Input 2: No</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input">
    <strong>Test 2</strong>
    <div class="text">
      <input type="text" value="test 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-1-yes" name="input-2" value="Input 3: Yes">
   <label for="input-3-yes">Input 3: Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-4-no" name="input-2" value="Input 4: No" checked>
   <label for="input-4-no">Input 4: No</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-5-yes" name="input-3" value="Input 5: Yes">
   <label for="input-5-yes">Input 5: Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-6-no" name="input-3" value="Input 6: No" checked>
   <label for="input-6-no">Input 6: No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="debug-template">
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="debug-container">
</div>

<div class="button">
  <button>Build Object</button>
</div>
```

Expected output:-

```
{
  0: {
    text: 'test',
    radio: {
      '0': 'Input 1: Yes'
    }
  },
  1: {
    text: 'test 2',
    radio: {
      '0': 'Input 4: No',
      '1': 'Input 6: No'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: Should you have added `this` instead of `this.obj` to the array?

Comment: Problem is `var index = $(this).parent().parent().prevAll().length;` . Look at values it produces. What exactly is your intent with that?

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as charlieftl. This makes no sense. If you log `index` each time you'll see that 3 times it outputs 0 and 5 times it outputs 1. So then when you come to populate the `inputs` array, you keep overwriting the same indexes with different values. Hence you only ever get two items output. Also your "text" and "radio" properties get populated with the same thing. It would really help if you could show us what you want as the correct output. Just saying "I want to make an object" doesn't give us enough detail to go on, we need to know what the object should contain

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But what should be in `[array]`? We can't guess. We can make it write the word "array" if you want but I suspect that's not your intention.

Comment: @CalvinNunes, I've edited my post added the expected output

Comment: Ok thanks. Can I gently suggest that `['Input 1: Yes', 'Input 4: No']` is not a very machine-readable format. What are you intending to do with this data once you extract it?

Comment: @ADyson I have included in my post

Comment: @ADyson I'm going to build html from the result

Comment: I see. Well maybe it will be adequate then. If you were going to send it to a server or something it wouldn't really be sufficient. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @CatherineSalvador added an answer, please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on your desired output, I needed to make some modifications on your code logic...

Insted of looping directly all `<input>`, loop through the `div.input` then creates the object and get its `id`. After that, loop through each `input` element that is inside the div, check if it is a `text` or a `radio` type, if radio, check if it is checked then push or not to the `obj` radio object.

see below code please.

**-> EDIT <-**
 
Once you said that the desired output needs to be an outer `object` instead of an array, and the object.radio should be another object, then I modified code as below:

```js
var data = {};

$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.input').each(function(i) {
    let index = $(this).index();    
    var obj = {};    
    var radioCount = 0
    obj.text = "";
    obj.radio = {};
    
    $(this).find("input").each((idx, elem) => {
      if (elem.type == "text"){
        obj.text = elem.value;
      }else if (elem.type == "radio" && elem.checked == true){
        obj.radio[radioCount] = (elem.value);
        radioCount++;
      }
    });
    data[i] = obj;
  });
  
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="input">
    <div class="text">
      <input type="text" value="test" />
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-1-yes" name="input-1" value="Input 1: Yes" checked/>
   <label for="input-1-yes">Input 1: Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-1-no" name="input-1" value="Input 1: No"/>
   <label for="input-2-no">Input 2: No</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input">
    <div class="text">
      <input type="text" value="test 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-1-yes" name="input-2" value="Input 3: Yes"/>
   <label for="input-3-yes">Input 3: Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-4-no" name="input-2" value="Input 4: No" checked/>
   <label for="input-4-no">Input 4: No</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-5-yes" name="input-3" value="Input 5: Yes"/>
   <label for="input-5-yes">Input 5: Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-6-no" name="input-3" value="Input 6: No" checked/>
   <label for="input-6-no">Input 6: No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="debug-template">
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="debug-container">
</div>

<div class="button">
  <button>Build Object</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost but not quite. Note that the desired output has an object as the outer wrapper, not an array. Whether that's the best solution is another matter but that's what was requested.

Comment: Right, I got it, I'll wait until the asker give some comment here, if she really needs the object format, then I'll edit my answer to fit it. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Added an snippet that outputs an object now.

Comment: @CalvinNunes cool... looks this is the solution. however, is it possible to make the "radio" as object instead of array? sorry, I forgot to edit my post that it should be object as well.... thank u

Comment: I'll edit my answer once again. But first, let me know: the final result shoud be: an `object` that have a `text` property that is a string and a `radio` property that is an `object` containing each check `radio`? Right?

Comment: ok, final edit made. Check it. I suggest to edit your question showing the final desired output.

Comment: cool... @CalvinNunes thank you so much for your help :) yep... I will edit it.. thank u

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it via jQuery [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method like:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    const data = $('.input').map(function(idex, elem) {
        return {
            text: $(elem).find('[type="text"]').val(),
            radio: $(elem).find('[type="radio"]:checked').map(function(i, el){
                return $(el).next('label').text();
            }).get()
        }    
    }).get();
    const mainData = {};
    data.map(function(value, index){
        mainData[index] = value;
    });
    console.log(mainData);
});
```

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  const data = $('.input').map(function(idex, elem) {
    return {
      text: $(elem).find('[type="text"]').val(),
      radio: $(elem).find('[type="radio"]:checked').map(function(i, el){
      return $(el).next('label').text();
      }).get()
    }    
  }).get();
  const mainData = {};
  data.map(function(value, index){
    mainData[index] = value;
  });
  console.log(mainData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="input">
    <strong>Test 1</strong>
    <div class="text">
      <input type="text" value="test" />
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-1-yes" name="input-1" value="Input 1: Yes" checked>
   <label for="input-1-yes">Input 1: Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-1-no" name="input-1" value="Input 1: No">
   <label for="input-2-no">Input 2: No</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input">
    <strong>Test 2</strong>
    <div class="text">
      <input type="text" value="test 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-1-yes" name="input-2" value="Input 3: Yes">
   <label for="input-3-yes">Input 3: Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-4-no" name="input-2" value="Input 4: No" checked>
   <label for="input-4-no">Input 4: No</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-5-yes" name="input-3" value="Input 5: Yes">
   <label for="input-5-yes">Input 5: Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="input-6-no" name="input-3" value="Input 6: No" checked>
   <label for="input-6-no">Input 6: No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button">
  <button>Build Object</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply @rohit-sharma, some div contains multiple input, so I need to get the radio values on each div

Comment: Here you can get view snippet.

Comment: @RohitSharma the question has been clarified with expected output, you may wish to update your answer to match

Comment: Check the OP's desired output again, particularly the fact that the outer part should be an object, not an array.

Comment: @ADyson Updated again.